# Using Table data type in a local variable in a sql server 2008 stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using table type in my variable `@temporaltable`

```
FETCH MyCursor Into @temporaltable
```

but when I try to get on e field I got an error...

```
insert into T1 (t1field1,t1field2, t1field3) 
values(@temporaltable.field1, @temporaltable.field2, @temporaltable.field3)
```

it doesn't recognize `@temporaltable` and I got error

> Must declare the scalar variable  @temporaltable

Comment: I think You need to fetch the fields from cursor into individual variables and then you have to give those variables in the insert satement. Actually to insert data from one table to another you dont have to use any cursor.

Comment: I have more logic inside the query for a cursor this is more complicate that I wrote...

Answer (score 0):

This syntax should help, obviously substituting for correct data types, tables names and select statements.

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE 
( 
    ... 
) 

DECLARE @var1 [DataType]
DECLARE @var2 [DataType]
DECLARE @var3 [DataType]

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT ....
    FROM .....
OPEN myCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @var1, @var2, @var3

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO T1 ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3]) VALUES (@var1, @var2, @var3)

    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @var1, @var2, @var3
END

CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Comment: OK. but no need to use cursor to copy from one table to another.

Comment: I completely agree, but the question was around cursors (which should be used with extreme caution)

Comment: I don't want to use individual variables, there are a lots fields only I want to know how can I have to use in insert into ...  values

Comment: @Eliana sorry you can't use a cursor like an object. However if it is complex you might want to look at using CLR integration which *may* be a more appropriate solution - but you will need to provide more detail

Comment: Thanks Kane!!, I'm migrating Clarion source code to stored procedures. the function is very complex,  working with differents sql tables populating local queues, spliiting some values in a queue and finally returning a global queue...  to do this I decide to work with temporal tables and cursor in my stored procedure. I haven't to much experience in PL-SQL